# Order By Alphabetically Not Working For Data Saved as Blob?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp, sql-order-by

I'm querying from my `DRIVER` and `CAR` tables and trying to order my results list by `name` alphabetically (`ASC`, `a-z`).  However, my results table isn't reflecting my `sql` statement as it's not ordered by alphabetical order at all:  (`Joe, Lucas, James, Ginny` should be displayed as `Ginny, James, Joe, Lucas`).

I have encrypted these `name` values using `RSA Encryption` before storing them in my `DRIVER` table as `BLOB` data types.  Could that be affecting why my query isn't being ordered the way I want it to?

Details below.

My **tables**:

```
DRIVER (driverID, username, name,....)

CAR (license, brand,....)
```

My **results** table printout:

```
Driver ID | username | Name  | License Plate | Brand
----------------------------------------------------
004       | joe867   | Joe   | M8M UZX       | Toyota
001       | luke99   | Lucas | A99 PX3       | Hyundai
003       | james3   | James | YPL 393       | Ford
002       | ginny23  | Ginny | HP2 111       | Subaru
```

My `selectDriver()` **query** method (things like method name brackets, try-catch, etc. have been omitted for simplicity).

```
String sql = "SELECT driverID, username, name, license, brand
FROM driver, car
WHERE driver.driverID = car.driverID_FK
ORDER BY name ;"

PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();

List<Driver> list = new ArrayList<Driver>();

while (rs.next()){

   Driver driver = new Driver(); //My Driver bean class
   driver.setDriverID(rs.getInt(1));
   driver.setUsername(rs.getString(2));
   ...
   driver.setBrand(rs.getString(5));
   list.add(driver);
}

rs.close();
connect.close();
return list;
```

My **JSP** with JSTL results table:

```
<table>
   <tr>
     <th>Driver ID</th>
     <th>Username</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>License Plate</th>
     <th>Brand</th>
   </tr>

   <c:forEach var="driver" items="${driverArray}">
   <tr>
      <td><c:out value="${driver.driverID }"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${driver.username }"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${driver.name }"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${driver.license }"/></td>
      <td><c:out value="${driver.brand }"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>    
</table>
```

Comment: Does your car table have a name column?

Comment: My `Driver` table has the `name` column

Comment: Yes, a set of RSA encrypted strings doesn't sort the same way as that same set of strings would unencrypted.  Your code doesn't show any encryption decryption though. Also, why are you encrypting these names separately?

Comment: I'm doing the encryption/decryption in my `Driver` model class.  How may I go around this issue once I have my `name` decrypted into plain `String`?

Comment: You can try sorting your list of drivers after you get it from the database, I don't see how you're going to do this from inside of sql.

Answer (score 0):

Just need a small change. Write your query like

```
String sql = "SELECT driverID, username, name, license, brand
FROM driver, car
WHERE driver.driverID = car.driverID_FK
ORDER BY driver.name ;"
```

Hope it will work !